# Где хранить инстанс глобального объекта?

Tags: python, ооп

На Python создаю приложение, которое имеет функции-обработчики событий. Они находятся в отдельном модуле. Есть объект, который создается при старте программы, к которому должны обращаться обработчики. Как правильно обращаться из обработчиков к этому объекту?

Comment: Ну, можно веб-сервис поднять на `flask` и обращаться к нему. Это самое простое и универсальное решение, тогда вообще не важно как разнесены эти модули, они могут быть хоть на разных серверах в разных концах земного шара.

Comment: можно все функции обработчики засунуть в один класс, затем передавать в этот класс главный объект и функции будут обращаться к атрибуту экземпляра класса - тому самому объекту